# SELECT in SQL Server - alternative to SUBQUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

I have a SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT 
T1.COD,
T1.NAME, 
(SELECT MAX(T2.DATA)
  FROM dbo.TAB2 T2
  WHERE T2.COD = T1.COD) AS ENDDATA
FROM dbo.TAB1 AS T1 WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Is there an alternative to use SUBQUERY? Is it possible to use JOIN?

I have to find a more efficient solution to run this query.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Subquery is fine as w/o it you'd have to `left (select max(data), code from dbo.tab2 group by code) t2 on t1.code = t2.code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use JOIN:

```
SELECT 
   T1.COD,
   T1.NAME, 
   MAX(T2.DATA) AS ENDDATA
FROM dbo.TAB1 AS T1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
JOIN dbo.TAB2 T2 WITH (NOLOCK) -- Assumed
  ON T2.COD = T1.COD
GROUP BY
   T1.COD,
   T1.NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

To return the same results as your original query, you need the following:

```
SELECT T1.COD, T1.NAME, s.ENDDATA
FROM dbo.TAB1 T1 WITH (NOLOCK)  left outer join
     (SELECT t2.cod, MAX(T2.DATA) as EndData
      FROM dbo.TAB2 T2
      group by T2.COD
     ) s
     on t1.cod = s.cod
```

Doing the group by outside the join changes the semantics of the query.  In particular, you would be returning only one row per COD/NAME, even though there may be duplicates in T1.  This may be desireable.  But, your original query would have the duplicates.

Also, why do you have a NOLOCK on TAB1 but not on TAB2 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   T1.COD,
         T1.NAME, 
         MAX(T2.DATA)
FROM     TAB1 AS T1
JOIN     TAB2 AS T2
ON       T2.COD = T1.COD
GROUP BY T1.COD,
         T1.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to use subselect? You can replace it with *outer apply* statement (which looks better from my point of view) but in the most cases you will get the same execution plan. Yes, actually it depends on your indexes (I assume that you have index on COD in TAB2 table) and data (I assume that row count in both table is more or less big and row count in TAB2 is definitely bigger than row count in TAB1).

Solution with grouping by COD and NAME is the worst solution. Solution with subquery is identical to outer apply. Solution with outer apply is more or less good solution (even better to use cross apply but in such case you should be sure that you don't have rows in TAB1 without associated rows in TAB1).